# Connection between LTI filters and damped + driven harmonic oscillator?

Tags: filters, filter-design, infinite-impulse-response, oscillator

In physics, a [damped harmonic oscillator that is driven by a sinusoidal force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_oscillator#Sinusoidal_driving_force) has a steady state solution:

$$
x(t) = \frac{F_0}{m Z_m \omega} \sin(\omega t + \varphi)
$$

where

$$
Z_m = \sqrt{\left(2\omega_0\zeta\right)^2 + \frac{1}{\omega^2} (\omega_0^2 - \omega^2)^2}
$$

is the absolute value of linear response function. This is also called the harmonic oscillator spectrum. For instance, for a given undamped angular frequency $\omega_0$ and various different damping ratios $\zeta$, the spectrum looks like this:

[image]

On first glance this has some resemblance with the frequency response of a linear filter. I'm wondering if there is a deeper connection between these two concepts. In particular:

- Is it possible to come up with some digital IIR filter that exactly corresponds to a damped harmonic oscillator, i.e., where the frequency response matches the harmonic oscillator spectrum exactly?
- If matching the harmonic oscillator spectrum exactly is not possible, is there e.g. a second order IIR filter that comes close to it?

In both cases I'd be curious if these filter have a name and how one can obtain the filter coefficients when starting from the oscillator parameters $\omega_0$ and $\zeta$?

*To be clear, I'm referring to digital / discrete time filters.*

Comment: I should mention that I'm referring to *digital* filters. So of course a key difference between the two concepts is that time is continuous in a harmonic oscillator, but discrete in a digital filter. The connection between the two may actually come down to numerical approximation of the derivative in the differential equation: I'd expect that e.g. the `dx/dt` term (associated with damping) can be approximated by the difference of `y_n` and `y_n-1`, which can be associated with "velocity". The `d^2x/dt^2` term may require a second order numerical approximation.

Comment: Absolutely!  The usual technique is to transform from a continuous-time, $s$-domain, description of the system into a discrete-time, $z$-domain description of the system.  The match won't be exact because of sampling and associated effects, but it can generally get as close as needed.  For example, [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/62753/80) shows how the bi-linear transform works.

Comment: You may wish to _edit your question_ to make it clear that you're talking about sampled-time filters.

Comment: @TimWescott: I had already done so, but perhaps the edit was too subtle. I've emphasized it now.

Answer (score 1):

If your physics department's damped harmonic oscillator happens to be linear and time-invariant with a defined input and output, and if there's only one oscillator rather than a chain of them coupled together, then it can be described with a Laplace-domain transfer function of the form

$$H(s) = \frac{N(s)}{s^2 + 2 \zeta \omega_0s + \omega_0^2} \tag 1$$

where $N(s)$ isn't arbitrary, but, depending on what the input is driving and the output is sampling, will be no more than a second-order polynomial in $s$.

The plots that you give are for a lowpass filter with a transfer function
$$H(s) = \frac{\omega_0^2}{s^2 + 2 \zeta \omega_0s + \omega_0^2} \tag 2$$

> Is it possible to come up with some digital IIR filter that exactly corresponds to a damped harmonic oscillator, i.e., where the frequency response matches the harmonic oscillator spectrum exactly?

(Note that I'm taking "digital filter" here to be synonymous with "sampled-time filter" -- the terms aren't exactly the same, but the colloquial meaning of "digital filter" comes close).

No and yes.

Can you make a sampled-time system* that takes a continuous signal, samples it, processes it, and emits the processed version, that will replicate the continuous-time prototype?

No.  No you can't.  Because aliasing will kill you.

Can you put that sampled-time system in between a continuous-time anti-alias filter at its input and a continuous-time reconstruction filter at its output** and replicate the spectrum of the continuous-time prototype?

No.  No you can't -- but you can come arbitrarily close.  You can't get there entirely because your continuous-time prototype has a non-zero response that extends to infinite frequencies, and your as-built system will *still* have aliasing.  So your "comes close" will involve too much attenuation (hopefully) above your frequency of interest, and at least some aliasing of higher-frequency content into your frequency of interest.

Can you make a model of a continuous-time linear system in sampled time that will *exactly replicate the observed behavior* of that continuous-time linear system as it is stimulated by a signal from your sampled-time system, with the output observed at the sampler?

Yes, yes you can.  It's been discussed here on this Stackexchange, but I can't find it -- here's the [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discretization#Discretization_of_linear_state_space_models) for how you do it assuming a zero-order hold at the output of your sampled-time system, and no additional delay anywhere.

---

* I'm sticking to strict math-theory land here when I say "sampled-time system"

** This would be a good model of board that has anti-aliasing filtering, an ADC, digital signal processing of some sort, a DAC, and a reconstruction filter.